# SQL Reporting Services report only loads on second click

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, asp.net-3.5

I have a local .rdlc report rigged to show on a button click, but for some reason the report only shows up on the 2nd button click event.  I have no idea why the report doesn't show on the first button click... This is the function I call on the click event of the button.

```
private void ShowReport(string accountingCompanyId, string companyId, string approvalUnitId, DateTime startDate, DateTime finishDate, string supplierId,
                    string documentNumber, string documentType, string documentState, string costCenterId, string chargingKeyId,
                    string dim1Value, string dim1Description, string dim1Id, string dim2Value, string dim2Description, string dim2Id,
                    string dim3Value, string dim3Description, string dim3Id, bool showDetails) {

        //this.ReportViewer1.Reset();

        //Set report mode for local processing.
        this.ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;

        ISettingsReader settingsReader = SettingsReaderFactory.Instance.CreateSettingsReader();
        this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = settingsReader.GetSetting("ReportViewer", "FinancialReportPath" + (showDetails ? "" : "Small"), true, null);

        ReportsBL reports = new ReportsBL();

        // Clear out any previous datasources.
        this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

        // Load the company dataSource.
        DataTable company = reports.GetCompanyDataSet(accountingCompanyId).Tables[0];
        ReportDataSource dataSourceCompany = new ReportDataSource(company.TableName, company);
        this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(dataSourceCompany);

        // Load the dataSource.
        DataTable report = reports.GetReportFinanceiroSmallDataSet(companyId, startDate, finishDate, chargingKeyId, costCenterId, documentNumber, documentType, dim1Value, dim2Value, dim3Value, dim1Id, dim2Id, dim3Id, supplierId, approvalUnitId, documentState, accountingCompanyId).Tables[0];
        ReportDataSource dataSourceReport = new ReportDataSource(report.TableName, report);
        this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(dataSourceReport);

        this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();

        this.pnlReport.Visible = true;
    }
```

Strangely, if I uncomment the line this.ReportViewer.Reset(); then the report will never show up regardless of the number of clicks I generate...  Does anybody know if this is normal? How can work around the problem?
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I got it working by calling the databind() method on the the pageload event.  After the pageload databinds (with no datasource set), the subsequent
button click starts working as expected.

I'm included the code in case somebody else encounters this error.  (Would love to know why I need to databind in the pageload though...)

**Update 2**

I finally figured out the problem...  Turns out the .rdlc was migrated from an old 2005 .rdl report, and that the new .rdlc contained old report parameters+sql which was somehow messing up the report loading.  After I removed the unused report parameteres+sql everything started working perfectly...  I've updated the code bellow to reflect what I'm now using in my project...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {

}

protected void btGenStats_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {

    ...

    this.ShowReport(accountingCompanyId, companyId, approvalUnitId, startDate, finishDate, supplierId, documentNumber, documentType, documentState,
                    costCenterId, chargingKeyId, dim1, dim1Desc, dim1Id, dim2, dim2Desc, dim2Id, dim3, dim3Desc, dim3Id, showDetails);
}

private void ShowReport(string accountingCompanyId, string companyId, string approvalUnitId, DateTime startDate, DateTime finishDate, string supplierId, string documentNumber, string documentType, string documentState, string costCenterId, string chargingKeyId, string dim1Value, string dim1Description, string dim1Id, string dim2Value, string dim2Description, string dim2Id, string dim3Value, string dim3Description, string dim3Id, bool showDetails) {

    this.ReportViewer1.Reset();

    //Set report mode for local processing.
    this.ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;

    ISettingsReader settingsReader = SettingsReaderFactory.Instance.CreateSettingsReader();
    string reportPath = settingsReader.GetSetting("ReportViewer", "FinancialReportPath"+( showDetails? "" : "Small" ), true, null);
    this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath(reportPath);

    ReportsBL reports = new ReportsBL();

    // Clear out any previous datasources.
    this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

    // Load the company dataSource.
    DataTable company = reports.GetCompanyDataSet(accountingCompanyId).Tables[0];
    ReportDataSource dataSourceCompany = new ReportDataSource(company.TableName, company);
    this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(dataSourceCompany);

    if (showDetails)
    {
        // Load the dataSource.
        DataTable report = reports.GetReportFinanceiroDataSet(companyId, approvalUnitId, startDate, finishDate, chargingKeyId, costCenterId, documentNumber, documentType, dim1Value, dim2Value, dim3Value, dim1Id, dim2Id, dim3Id, supplierId, documentState, accountingCompanyId).Tables[0];
        ReportDataSource dataSourceReport = new ReportDataSource(report.TableName, report);
        this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(dataSourceReport);
    }
    else
    {
        // Load the dataSource.
        DataTable report = reports.GetReportFinanceiroSmallDataSet(companyId, approvalUnitId, startDate, finishDate, chargingKeyId, costCenterId, documentNumber, documentType, dim1Value, dim2Value, dim3Value, dim1Id, dim2Id, dim3Id, supplierId, documentState, accountingCompanyId).Tables[0];
        ReportDataSource dataSourceReport = new ReportDataSource(report.TableName, report);
        this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(dataSourceReport);
    }

    this.pnlReport.Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess the problem might be that the click event is fired after the page is rendered. Try calling the method in the `Page_Load` event.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsCallback)
    {
        ShowReport(
            // params
        );
    }
}
```

If that works, you know it has something to do with the order of execution.

Answer (score 2):

I've never had to call ReportViewer.DataBind(); Below is what I typically do:

```
IEnumerable<ReportClass> ds = DataTranslator.GetReportData(Int64.Parse(<someId>));
report.LocalReport.ReportPath = "<some_path_to_report.rdlc>";
report.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet", ds));
report.Visible = true;
report.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Comment: But you do this on the pageload method, or you do it on the onclick method?  What version of the ReportViewer do you use?

Comment: I call the method via a postback control. I pulled this specifically from a DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged event. I am using ReportViewer.WebForms Version 10.0.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
  protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string pstrType;
            pstrType = Request.QueryString["Type"];           
            LoadReport();
        }

        public class CustomReportCredentials : Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.IReportServerCredentials
        {
            // local variable for network credential.
            private string _UserName;
            private string _PassWord;
            private string _DomainName;
            public CustomReportCredentials(string UserName, string PassWord, string DomainName)
            {
                _UserName = UserName;
                _PassWord = PassWord;
                _DomainName = DomainName;
            }
            public System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity ImpersonationUser
            {
                get
                {
                    return null;  // not use ImpersonationUser
                }
            }
            public System.Net.ICredentials NetworkCredentials
            {
                get
                {
                    // use NetworkCredentials
                    return new NetworkCredential(_UserName, _PassWord, _DomainName);
                }
            }
            public bool GetFormsCredentials(out Cookie authCookie, out string user, out string password, out string authority)
            {
                // not use FormsCredentials unless you have implements a custom autentication.
                authCookie = null;
                user = password = authority = null;
                return false;
            }
        }

        void LoadReport()
        {
            string strCompanyName = objSession.SelCompanyName;
            string strHeading = "";
            string strBranchName = objSession.SelBranchName;
            rptvwMain.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
            rptvwMain.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = new CustomReportCredentials(AppConfig.ReportServerUserName, AppConfig.ReportServerPassword, AppConfig.ReportServerDomain);
            string strReportServerUrl = AppConfig.ReportServerUrl + AppConfig.ReportServerFolder;
            rptvwMain.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(strReportServerUrl);
            List<ReportParameter> parameters = new List<ReportParameter>();
    if (pstrType == "OB")
            {
                strHeading = "Ledger Opening Balance";
                rptvwMain.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Account/OpeningBalance";
            }


            parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("FyId", Convert.ToInt16(objSession.FyId).ToString()));
            parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("AccountGroupId", cmbAccountGroup.SelectedValue));
            parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("LedgerId", cmbLedgerId.SelectedValue));
            parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("BranchId", Convert.ToInt64(objSession.BranchId).ToString()));
            parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("StDate", Convert.ToDateTime(RadDtpFromDate.SelectedDate).ToString()));
            parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("EnDate", Convert.ToDateTime(RadDtpToDate.SelectedDate).ToString()));
            parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("CompanyName", strCompanyName.ToString()));
            parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("BranchName", strBranchName.ToString()));
            parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("Heading",strHeading.ToString()));
            rptvwMain.ServerReport.SetParameters(parameters);

            rptvwMain.ServerReport.SetDataSourceCredentials(new[] { new DataSourceCredentials() { Name =AppConfig.ReportServerDataSource , UserId = AppConfig.ReportServerDSUserName, Password = AppConfig.ReportServerDSPassword } });
            rptvwMain.ShowZoomControl = true;
            rptvwMain.ServerReport.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

Comment: In general, when solving a problem with code on Stack Overflow, it is most helpful to explain _how_ the code solves the problem, or what the question author's bug/issue was.